# add custom content to appearance/widgets screen

Tags: customization, wp-admin

My client don`t really understands wp so I need to add some explanatory text.

Is there a way to add some guidance text in the appearance/widgets page like "To edit front-page elements go to appearance/customize/front-page-settings", or maybe a link to that?

Answer (score 1):

found a hook here: http://hookr.io/actions/widgets_admin_page/

```
// define the widgets_admin_page callback 
function action_widgets_admin_page(  ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'widgets_admin_page', 'action_widgets_admin_page', 10, 0 );
```